# Getting specific part of a string

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am trying to parse through a string which i create after getting a response from an API.

this is the string i am trying to parse:

```
// API callback
translateText({
 "data":{
  "translations":[
  {
   "translatedText": "Ola Mundo",
   "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"
  }
 ]
}
}
);
```

i want to be able to get the Translated text "Ola Mundo", but i don't want to just search through it and get that specific text, as this Text maybe different the next time.

Comment: This question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a valid JSON object , one option is to convert the string to a JSON object using Jackson library or something else , after that you can get anything you want .

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that with the following [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/cQ6uJ2/1):

```
translatedText": (.*?),
```

In Java, you approach to the result with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you you remove the `translateText();` part and just have:

> {  "data":{   "translations":[   {    "translatedText": "Ola Mundo", 
>   "detectedSourceLanguage": "en"   }  ] } }

its a valid JSON object and you can easily use a library to parse it. [See this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) This way is recommend if you want to access the data securely.

Comment: i cant remove anything from the string as it automatically generated code

Comment: You could just make a new string and remove the first 13 characters and the last 2.